# OAF Change page's layout in XML

Tags: xml, oracle

The following code arranges table in the way shown in the picture.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<oa:tableLayout version="9.0.3.8.10_1080" xml:lang="en-US" width="100%">
   <ui:contents>
      <oa:rowLayout id="SpacerRow0">
         <ui:contents>
            <oa:cellFormat id="SpacerCell0" height="12"/>
         </ui:contents>
      </oa:rowLayout>
      <oa:rowLayout id="PesonCommonInfoRow">
         <ui:contents>
            <oa:cellFormat id="PesonCommonInfoCell">
               <ui:contents>
                  <oa:tableLayout id="DataRN" hAlign="center" controllerClass="oracle.apps.xxvip.sshr.common.webui.PersonCommonInfoCO" width="100%">
                     <ui:contents>
                        <oa:rowLayout id="PersonRow" width="100%" vAlign="middle">
                           <ui:contents>
                              <oa:cellFormat id="PhotoCell" vAlign="top">
                                 <ui:contents>
                                    <oa:image id="PersonPhoto" imageWidth="140" shortDesc="ФОТО сотрудника" destination="" source=""/>
                                 </ui:contents>
                              </oa:cellFormat>
                              <oa:cellFormat id="Spacer0Cell" width="50"/>
                              <oa:cellFormat id="CommonInfoCell" vAlign="top">
                                 <ui:contents>
                                    <oa:defaultSingleColumn id="CommonInfoRN" headerDisabled="true">
                                       <ui:contents>
                                          <oa:messageStyledText id="EmployeeNumber" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="Табельный номер" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="EmployeeNumber" maximumLength="30" styleClass="OraDataText"/>
                                          <oa:messageStyledText id="LastName" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="Фамилия" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="LastName" maximumLength="150" styleClass="OraDataText"/>
                                          <oa:messageStyledText id="FirstName" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="Имя" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="FirstName" maximumLength="150" styleClass="OraDataText"/>
                                          <oa:messageStyledText id="MiddleNames" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="Отчество" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="MiddleNames" maximumLength="60" styleClass="OraDataText"/>
                                          <oa:messageStyledText id="EmailAddress" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="E-mail" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="EmailAddress" maximumLength="240" styleClass="OraLinkText" destination="mailto:{@EmailAddress}"/>
                                          <oa:staticStyledText id="DoneByBeibut" prompt="HI" styleClass="ITRHomeTo"/>
                                       </ui:contents>
                                    </oa:defaultSingleColumn>
                                 </ui:contents>
                              </oa:cellFormat>
                              <oa:cellFormat id="Spacer1Cell" width="50"/>
                              <oa:cellFormat id="AssignCell" vAlign="top">
                                 <ui:contents>
                                    <oa:messageStyledText id="OrgName" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="OrgName" maximumLength="4000" styleClass="OraFieldText"/>
                                    <oa:spacer id="Spacer0" height="25"/>
                                    <oa:messageStyledText id="Position" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="Position" maximumLength="700" styleClass="OraFieldText"/>
                                    <oa:messageStyledText id="PL" dataType="VARCHAR2" prompt="" viewName="CommoPersonInfoVO1" viewAttr="PL" maximumLength="240" styleClass="OraDataText" rendered="false" />
                                 </ui:contents>
                              </oa:cellFormat>
                           </ui:contents>
                        </oa:rowLayout>
                     </ui:contents>
                  </oa:tableLayout>
               </ui:contents>
            </oa:cellFormat>
         </ui:contents>
      </oa:rowLayout>
      <oa:rowLayout id="SpacerRow01">
         <ui:contents>
            <oa:cellFormat id="SpacerCell01" height="1  2"/>
         </ui:contents>
      </oa:rowLayout>
   </ui:contents>
</oa:tableLayout>
```

The picture that shows what I have and what I need to do:
[image]

The big rectange is second row of the parent table. I am having troubles to adding a cell in the way shown in the picture. How is it possible to align such way? Do I need to add extra inner table? Thank you.